# SQL display values based on the id's from the joined table

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

Starting from the top, we have a simple table lets call it Employee_table

```
 [dbo.Employee_table]
 --------------------------
 Employee name | EmployeeID | BossID  
 Tom Something      11          23
 Mark Cole          54          32
 Samantha Cat       23          12
```

I have created a trigger that inserts in to another table [dbo.Employee_tableHistory] both old and new boss id on update.

```
[dbo.Employee_tableHistory]
---------------------------
  name      |        OldBossID  |    NewBossID
 Tom Something          23              12
 Mark Cole              32              32
 Samantha Cat           12              23
```

Then i have a procedure in which I want to return full name insted of the id's....source of all employees name is the first table  [dbo.Employee_table]

So for the final resault i want somthing like this :

```
 [dbo.finalResault]
---------------------------
  name      |        OldBossName    |    NewBossName
 Tom Something      Boss Bosserson      Barabrian Conan                 
 Mark Cole          Chief Master        Leonidos                    
 Samantha Cat       Shepard Commander   Gray Gandalf
```

Where all of the names and ids are coming from the first table.
The problem here is that when I try to join and display data by name...it takes the employee name insted of the bossname.

How can I go from [dbo.Employee_tableHistory] to [dbo.finalResault]?

Comment: Edit your question and show the query that you are using.

Comment: That will be hard since i have simplefied it here quite a bit. I will edit this in few minutes.

Comment: So BossID is the EmployeeID for the boss?

Comment: You need to show the queries you have written, and the code of the trigger

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How's this for a start?

```
SELECT
    e.EmployeeName,
    o.EmployeeName OldBossName
    b.EmployeeName NewBossName
FROM
    employee_table e
JOIN
    employee_table b ON e.BossId = b.EmployeeId
JOIN
    employee_tableHistory h ON e.EmployeeId = h.EmployeeId
JOIN
    employee_table o ON h.OldBossId = e.EmployeeId
```

Employee_Table_History should have an EmployeeId too.

Comment: Yes, that was exactly what i was looking for. Sorry for the vague explenation. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Since you don't have EmployeeId in the history table... this should work for your test data. Once the history table get's more populated you'll need to find the last entry, which ideally would bee off an ID column using `MAX()` or a date of insert column. Since you didn't list those, I didn't include them here though.

```
SELECT 
   e.[Employee name], 
   boss.[Employee name] as NewBossName,
   oldBoss.[Employee name] as OldBossName
FROM Employee_table e
INNER JOIN Employee_tableHistory b on b.name = e.[Employee name]
INNER JOIN Employee_table boss on boss.EmployeeID = b.NewBossID
INNER JOIN Employee_table oldBoss on oldBoss.EmployeeID = b.OldBossID
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes as Jonny suggested (and scsimon eluded to) but neither delved into the Employee_tableHistory should have an EmployeeId and actually this is even part of the problem which can be made simpler by fixing the table structures first.  It is a very bad idea to build a house on a faulty foundation and the same thing applies to Database development but some folks will just keep trying to shore up the problem making it bigger and bigger until it collapses and they have a big old mess — rather than fixing the foundation early on where the problem actually resides.  That said lets look at your issue from the ground up and work a more simpler solution for you.

```
 [dbo.tblEmployee]
 --------------------------
Employee_Id |  Employee_FirstName | Employee_LastName | BossType  
    11            Tom                  Something            0
    54            Mark                 Cole                 0
    23            Samantha             Cat                  0
    32            Chief                Masters              1
    12            Shepard              Commander            1
    17            Bill                 Bosserson            3
    21            Barbarian            Conan                2
    42            Larry                Leonidos             1
    25            Gary                 Gandalf              2
```

The Key to this table would of course be Employee_Id which when displaying and/or building we put first so that it is obvious further it is always a good idea to split the name into first and last because there will be times when you want it that way and it is a breeze to concatenate much harder to split

Now I added BossType in case you needed to know or verify that a particular employee was actually a boss and what level of boss they were because bosses can have bosses.  Also keep in mind that bosses are employees of the company as well even if they are the sole owner of a private company as the conceptual company is the over arching controller or parent of all

```
[dbo.tblEmployee_History]
---------------------------
  Employee_Id | Old_Boss_Id | New_Boss_Id
      11            17            21
      54            32            42
      23            12            25
```

Note while labeled differently the Old_Boss_Id and the New_Boss_Id are simply Employee_Ids originally pulled from the Employee table so they are technically foreign keys with the constraint if they do not exist in the Employee Table they cannot exist here

Now for the View to display the final results — we do the following

```
SELECT (e1.Employee_FirstName + “ “ + e1.Employee_LastName) AS Employee_Name
      ,(e2.Employee_FirstName + “ “ + e2.Employee_LastName) AS Old_Boss_Name
      ,(e3.Employee_FirstName + “ “ + e3.Employee_LastName) AS New_Boss_Name
  FROM dbo.tblEmployee_History bs
  JOIN dbo.tblEmployee e1
    ON em.Employee_Id = bs.Employee_Id
  JOIN dbo.tblEmployee e2
    ON em.Employee_Id = bs.Old_Boss_Id
  JOIN dbo.tblEmployee e3
    ON em.Employee_Id = bs.bs.New_Boss_Id;
```

Thus a much more solid solution and one that allows you to do more things in a simple way later on

Note I left the Join type off since in most SQL languages Join is understood to be Inner Join and I would leave it to you to determine which type of Join you ultimately want but I would strongly suggest picking one and being explicit with the type of Join you are going to use.

Comment: In the real world I would suggest a different approach where the Employee_History table holds the same columns as the Employee table but adding at least one date column.
I think I would add a "DateTimeFrom" and a "DateTimeTo" in the history table. This would be able to track all changes.

Comment: Normally duplicating data in a database is a bad idea and only under fairly exceptional cases is it ever needed.  Generally if you find that data has been duplicated that is your first sign that something was not designed properly.  Keep in mind that one of the major purposes of a relational database was to do away with data duplication and streamline data storage.  Of course, this does not stop it from being done.

Comment: Also keep in mind if you need to see the data in a different format for any reason that is what views are for and depending on the database they can be dynamic and/or semi-static views it all comes down to balancing between speed and complexity.  This is to say you can build a house with just a hammer and a saw -- or -- you can use all the tools in the tool wagon and get it done more efficiently